# How the WordPress nonce works?

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I add a nonce to form and it works fine but I have some questions.

If the form is used by 10000 users at the same time, the nonce will be different for each of them ?

The nonce is generated by WordPress every 12 hours, but what are the factors that influence and change his life ?

If I close the browser I will have the same nonce when I reopen the browser ?

If I turn off the computer and reboot, I will have the same nonce ?

If I connect to the Internet with different IP I will have the same nonce ?

If I change the browser I will have the same nonce ?

If I delete browsing history and cookies I will have the same nonce ?

Comment: nonce - "number used once". if it's used by multiple people, then it wouldn't be a nonce anymore.

Comment: that's not a real answer to this topic but not so far: "stored in user sessions. They are unique tokens stored in user's session. ... If the user logs out of WordPress, the nonces will no longer be valid...." ( copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535895/how-the-wordpress-nonce-works )

Answer (score 0):

WP nonce function creates a cryptographic token tied to a specific action, user and user session. It means each user is going to have its own token even for 10000 users.

> The nonce is generated by WordPress every 12 hours, but what are the factors that influence and change his life?

It is created via `wp_nonce_tick()` function which goes throuh a filter `nonce_life` and can be modified via this filter.  [wp_nonce_tick docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_tick/)

> If I close the browser I will have the same nonce when I reopen the browser?
>
> If I turn off the computer and reboot, I will have the same nonce?
>
> If I change the browser I will have the same nonce ?

If you are logged in and your session is the same you will have the same nonce token.

> If I connect to the Internet with different IP I will have the same nonce?

No. your session will be different and new token will be generated.

> If I delete browsing history and cookies I will have the same nonce?

No, your session will be changed since the session is stored in a browser cookie.

You should not rely only on the nonce check. You need also make sure you check  `current_user_can()` function as it is described [in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)